# After inviting friend there is no "Waiting for players" screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I saw many games that uses Google Play Services, in which when you invite a friend, you have "Waiting for players" window. But in my game after I send invitation, game just returns to it's activity without that screen.

I use this code to open invitation screen:

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.CreateWithInvitationScreen(1, 1, gameVariant, this);
```

Comment: You need to show this screen by yourself as described here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#optional_adding_a_waiting_room_ui

Comment: @AlexeyGorovoy Thanks! I didn't know that I need to call ShowWaitingRoomUI();